# creation of list of dictionary with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I tried to build list of dictionary  over loop, but it overrides elements of dict in every iteration , so i get list with one dictionary inside .

```
for element in elements:
  title = elements.get('test')
  content = elements.get('content')
  post_dict['titre'] = title
  post_dict['content'] = content
  list_elements.append(post_dict)
  print(list_elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

post_dict refers to the same dictionary object, this is why it is overwritten.

The solution is to create a new dictionary object:

```
for element in elements:
  d = {}
  title = elements.get('test')
  content = elements.get('content')
  d['title'] = title
  d['content'] = content
  list_elements.append(d)
  print(list_elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the data inside the only dict you have created.
you have to create a new dict in each iteration:

```
for element in elements:
  post_dict = {}
  title = elements.get('test')
  content = elements.get('content')
  post_dict['titre'] = title
  post_dict['content'] = content
  list_elements.append(post_dict)
  print(list_elements)
```

Comment: i added post_dict = {} but i still have the same issue , and the elements is big list so do i have to create a new dictionary for every iteration

Comment: i just realized, is it intentionally that you have used elements.get() instead of element.get()?

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you have to create a new dictionary and not update the same dict as you are doing.

```
for element in elements:
  post_dict = dict()
  title = elements.get('test')
  content = elements.get('content')
  post_dict['titre'] = title
  post_dict['content'] = content
  list_elements.append(post_dict)
print(list_elements)
```

Comment: i added post_dict = dict() but i still have the same issue

Comment: It's strange. Do you mind to show us a little bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer,  you should perhaps use element instead of elements. Else your item is basically not used at all in each loop iteration

```
for element in elements:
  post_dict = {}
  title = element.get('test')
  content = element.get('content')
  post_dict['titre'] = title
  post_dict['content'] = content
  list_elements.append(post_dict)
print(list_elements)
```